# MVC date range between min and max value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I am trying to add a range for date in my model.

I have added following property to my class

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Schedule")]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), DateTime.Now.AddDays(120).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), ErrorMessage = "Please select valid date")]
    public DateTime? DateSchedule { get; set; }
```

It gives me following **error**

[image]

How can I assign **Min** and **Max** value to my `DateSchedule`? In calendar control it should only display date from `today` to `120 days`(In my class I have added 120 days).

Answer (score 1):

Attributes accept only constants as parameters.

We know that `DateTime.Now` isn't a constant, it changes depending on when the code runs. and  Range attribute is determined at compile time.

You need to create custom validator as shown below :-

```
public class DateAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    ////your code
}
```